# Facebook App Store linking old app version

Tags: ios, app-store, facebook-apps, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a native iOS facebook app in the Facebook appstore. Now, 2 days ago, the latest version of our iOS app for better iOS 7 support and networking issues that made all previous versions of the app unusable was made available in the app store.

My problem is, when the users download the App by opening the App Store application on their phone and then downloading the app from there, everything works fine and the latest version of the app is installed.

But, if the user download our app by going in the Facebook App Store in the Facebook iOS app, and then downloading our app from a link in there, an older version of our native iOS app will be installed.

Since iOS 7, you can disable older version in the right and pricing section of your app in itunes connect. I disabled all previous versions of our app in there (did this today so maybe the chance did not propagate) but the Facebook App Store in the Facebook iOS app still links to our old version.

I checked our Facebook app settings to find a way to make sure the users are linked to our latest version with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue. This often lasts around an hour but I have noticed it taking up to a day or so. Give it some time and I am sure it will straightened itself out. I have not found any documentation about this issue but have heard of it happening quite often.

Comment: Indeed the problem was fixed the following hour, thank you brotha